# MochaJS is not waiting for async function

Tags: node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I want to write tests of an async function.

```
// Function declaration
someLongAsyncTasks(cb) {
    // This function doing some long tasks like fs.copy(...)
    // I will use setTimeout to simulate these jobs
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb();
    }, 3000);
}

// in tests.js file
it('...', function(done) {
    someLongAsyncTasks(function(err) {
        if (err) done(err);
        else done();
    });
});
```

As you see I'm passing `done` to `it()`'s callback function so it should wait until `someLongAsyncTasks()` finish its job. But I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

What I'm missing? Why `it()` is not waiting for my async function and firing timeout error?

Answer (score 0):

OK I will answer my own question. I figured out the problem. In real `someLongAsyncTasks()` function there are lots of different cases and one of these cases function is not calling the callback function.

**In shortly,**

Check your someLongAsyncTasks() function is calling your callback function in every situation.

Comment: Also: make sure that the code in your question actually exhibits the problem that you're trying to get solved.